# Can a class 1 medical certificate be obtained when glasses are needed to achieve 20/20?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

Will I be able to obtain an FAA/DGCA class 1 medical certificate if I have a power of -5.75 and -6.25 in both my eyes?

It says "you should be able to maintain 20/20 vision with/without glasses" and yes, I can achieve vision with glasses.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can (provided you don't have any other disqualifying conditions).

[14 CFR 67.103 Eye](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/67.103)

> **(a)** Distant visual acuity of 20/20 or better in each eye separately, with or without corrective lenses. If corrective lenses (spectacles or contact lenses) are necessary for 20/20 vision, the person may be eligible only on the condition that corrective lenses are worn while exercising the privileges of an airman certificate.
>   
>   **(b)** Near vision of 20/40 or better, Snellen equivalent, at 16 inches in each eye separately, with or without corrective lenses. If age 50 or older, near vision of 20/40 or better, Snellen equivalent, at both 16 inches and 32 inches in each eye separately, with or without corrective lenses.

In your case, you will have a limitation placed on your certificate that says that you must wear corrective lenses while performing the duties under your Class-1 medical certificate.

Comment: Thx. BTW is there a limit for the maximum power u must have in each eye (excluding JAR)

Comment: The FAR only states that it must be "correctable to 20/20". However if you have some kind of issue that causes issues like Amblyopia, you will need to get a special issuance. It is really rare for an AME or the FAA to reject a pilot based on vision problems unless they are degenerative or uncorrectable.

Comment: Or indicative of an underlying condition.